# Define a normalized vector field with xTensor

Tags: xact

I just started to learn how to use xAct and xTensor. I would like to define the following vector field on a manifold equipped with a Lorentzian metric.

My attempt was

```
DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e}]
DefMetric[-1, met[-a, -b], CD]
DefTensor[X[a], M]
DefTensor[u[a], M]
n = Sqrt[-X[b] X[-b]]
IndexSet[u[a], X[a]/n]
```

However, when evaluating `u[a]u[-a]` I get `-((X[-a]X[a])/(X[-f]X[f]))` that I would like to be simplified to $-1$.

Moreover, despite the use of abstract indices, I don't get what I expect entering e.g `u[b]`

Is there a way to solve both problems at once?

Comment: Do you have to normalize explicitly ? For this case you can maybe skip the normalization and use `TagSet` like `u /: u[-a_] u[a_] = -1`. For more complicated cases where there are introduced new indices on the right hand side of the rule and you want a rule to be applied automatically you could look into `AutomaticRules` in that package.

Comment: When I evaluated  u[-a]*u[a] with your code the u[-a] did not change,  I got (u[-a]   X[a])/Sqrt[- X[-b]  X[b]]

Comment: The xTensor documentation for [IndexSet](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_34.html) shows that the element on the left in the list has to be a pattern with  pattern objects `_`. This is not the case however for [MakeRule](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_60.html) as the indices for the element in the list on the left are automatically converted to patterns.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I used the `IndexSet[u[a_], X[a]/n]` as you suggested and it seems to work. However, it still doesn't simplify the norm of $u$ to $-1$, even with the assumption that the norm of $X$ is non-zero.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to use `u /: u[-a_]*u[a_] = -1` ? Doing that the vector is normalized without having to use an explicit normalization factor.

Comment: Yes, I need the other vector anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Discusion and context

I checked the xact google group and I did not find a clear or safe  answer to this question. In one of the answers [here](https://groups.google.com/g/xact/c/7hYa1fYagZM/m/Tht5zmCQCAAJ) the user was perhaps given a solution that modifies how xAct works and later the same person mentions a potential danger that explained why one of the potential solutions for this was not implemented. It is unclear to me whether the solution that the user provided before is safe or whether it would work here. Hence, I have refrained myself from trying that method. Instead, in the following I will give 3 possible solutions to this issue regarding normalization.

---

See references in the last section to search for functions that you might not be familiar with.

Functions in the text below that belong to the xAct/xTensor package will be followed by (xAct/xTensor).

---

#### Setting up definitions:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`;
DefManifold[M, 4, {a, b, c, d, e}];
DefMetric[-1, met[-a, -b], CD];
DefTensor[X[a], M];
DefTensor[u[a], M];(*normalized X*)
```

**Note**: If like me you finding all the printing that xact does each time one defines something then you could use `$DefInfoQ = False`

#### First solution: use [`UpValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) (maybe easiest/best generic solution)

I think the best/easiest solution would be to momentarily forget about the un-normalized vector `X` and to introduce it only when needed using :

```
expression /. IndexRule[u[a_],X[a]/normalization]
```

Then one could avoid explicit normalization of `u` and instead associate an [upvalue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) (a  property) to the normalized vector `u` using the same method as provided in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272711/86543) on stack exchange (without using `IndexSet[u[a_], X[a]/n]`(xAct/xTensor) and thus contrarily to the method in the original question) :

```
u /: u[-a_] u[a_] = -1
```

This has the benefit of keeping the equations clean without carrying around a normalization factor in certain expressions.

#### 2nd solution: not defining the normalization factor

If for whatever reason the user wishes to use `IndexSet[u[a], X[a]/normalization]`(xAct/xTensor) then one option might be to not use an explicit definition for the normalization:

```
DefConstantSymbol[normalization];
IndexSet[u[a_], X[a]/normalization];
```

Then one could use [MakeRule](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_60.html) (xAct/xTensor):

```
rule = MakeRule[{X[-a]*X[a], -normalization^2}];
```

and use

```
u[-c]*u[c] /. rule
```

`(* -1 *)`

```
u[-c]*u[c]*X[a]*X[b] /. rule
```

`(* - X[a]  X[b] *)`

Using rule each time could be tedious so one could use [AutomaticRules](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_60.html) (xAct/xTensor):

```
AutomaticRules[X, rule];
```

Now one no longer needs to use explicitly `rule`

```
u[-c]*u[c]
```

`(* -1 *)`

#### Third solution : use `Scalar`(xAct/xTensor) and `PutScalar`(xAct/xTensor)

If one would like to explicitly see something like $\frac{X^a}{\sqrt{-X^b X_b}}$ in the equations and thus define the normalization, then one should use [Scalar](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_65.html) (xAct/xTensor) to specify explicitly that $X^b X_b$ should be considered as a scalar/number and should always be grouped together under the head `Scalar`. Using `Scalar` is particularly important to prevent simplification from an expression like $\frac{X^a}{X^a X_a}$ if what was meant was $\frac{X^a}{\sum_b \left(X^b X_b\right)}$ when the Einstein notation is removed. That might also be important when computing derivatives. Other scenarios where `Scalar` could be needed is when taking squares of a scalar to prevent index clashes see the documentation page [here](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_65.html) for examples.

Explicit normalization:

```
n = (-Scalar[X[b] X[-b]])^(1/2);
IndexSet[u[a_], X[a]/n];
```

Simplification of $ u_c u^c $ using `PutScalar`(xAct/xTensor) and `Simplification`(xAct/xTensor):

```
u[-c]*u[c] // PutScalar // Simplification
```

`(* -1 *)`

#### References

I found it difficult to find the documentation with the xact website. Here is a list of references mainly for `xTensor` and `xTras`:

- xTensor Guide : http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/xTensorDoc.nb.html
- List of xTensor functions with short documentation, link to discussion on the function and "See also" (like in the bottom of help pages in Mathematica) : http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensor/
- xTras documentation : http://www.xact.es/xtras/documentation/guide/xTras.html
- xTras paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3493
- xAct google group for searching and asking questions about xAct: https://groups.google.com/g/xAct